# Calculated solution is not recognized as value

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse, luacode

In the code below it should be checked if treq<t.

In TEST 1, treq is specified as 2.93.
The condition treq<t is met and turns blue (or red).
\ifthenelse condition works fine.

In TEST 2, xreq is calculated using formula.
The \ifthenelse condition does not work?! What's going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your reply.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{luacode}
    t  = 3
    s  = 454
    p  = 4.51
    k  = 0.00394
    w  = 7.04
    a  = 1.5
\end{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
    sqrt = math.sqrt

    treq = function (t, s, p, k, w, a) 
            return k *s * sqrt(p / w) + a 
    end

    print = function (d,s) 
        if d == 0 then
         format = "%d"
        else
         format = "%." .. d .. "f"
        end
        tex.sprint(string.format(format,s));
    end
\end{luacode*}

\def\luaprint#1{\directlua{tex.print(#1)}}
\newcommand{\lp}[2][16]{\directlua{print(#1,#2)}}

\begin{document}
%===========================
% CALCULATION WITH CONDITION
% treq is specified here
%===========================
\section{Test 1}
\def\t{\luaprint{t}}
\def\treq{2.93}

t = \t \\

treq = \treq \\

The plating t is to be not less in thickness than treq =\treq

\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\treq pt < \t pt}}
{{\color{blue}treq < t}}
{{\color{red}treq > t}}

\bigskip

%===========================
% CALCULATION WITH CONDITION
% xreq is calculated. Why is xreq not recognized as value 2.93 ?????
%===========================
\section{Test 2}
\def\xreq{
\lp[2]{treq(\luaprint{t}, \luaprint{s}, \luaprint{p}, \luaprint{k}, \luaprint{w}, \luaprint{a})}
}

t = \t \\

treq = \xreq \\

The plating t is to be not less in thickness than treq =\xreq

\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\xreq pt < \t pt}}
{{\color{blue}xreq < t}}
{{\color{red}xreq > t}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't redefine `print` unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also think that's the problem. A good example would be very welcome.